# Survival Curves For Cox PH Models. Checking My Understanding About Plotting Them

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Im using the book Applied Survival Analysis Using R by Moore to try and model some time-to-event data.  The issue I'm running into is plotting the estimated survival curves from the cox model. Because of this I'm wondering if my understanding of the model is wrong or not. My data is simple: a time column **t**, an event indicator column (1 for event 0 for censor) **i**, and a predictor column with 6 factor levels **p**.

I believe I can plot estimated surival curves for a cox model as follows below.  But I don't understand how to use survfit and baseplot, nor functions from survminer to achieve the same end. Here is some generic code for clarifying my question. I'll use the pharmcoSmoking data set to demonstrate my issue.

```
library(survival)
library(asaur)
t<-pharmacoSmoking$longestNoSmoke
i<-pharmacoSmoking$relapse
p<-pharmacoSmoking$levelSmoking
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(t,i,p))
model <- coxph(Surv(data$t, data$i) ~ p, data=data)
```

As I understand it, with the following code snippets, modeled after book examples,  a baseline (cumulative) hazard at my reference factor level for **p** may be given from

`base<-basehaz(model, centered=F)`

An estimate of the survival curve is given by

```
s<-exp(-base$hazard)
t<-base$time
plot(s~t, typ = "l")
```

The survival curve associated with a different factor level may then be given by

```
beta_n<-model$coefficients #only one coef in this case
s_n <- s^(exp(beta_n))
lines(s_n~t)
```

where beta_n is the coefficient for the nth factor level from the cox model.  The code above gives what I think are estimated survival curves for heavy vs light smokers in the pharmcoSmokers dataset.

Since thats a bit of code I was looking to packages for a one-liner solution, I had a hard time with the documentation for Survival ( there weren't many examples in the docs) and also tried survminer.  For the latter I've tried:

```
library(survminer)
ggadjustedcurves(model, variable ="p" , data=data)
```

This gives me something different than my prior code, although it is similar.  Is the method I used earlier incorrect? Or is there a different methodology that accounts for the difference? The survminer code doesn't work from my data (I get a 'can't allocated vector of size yada yada error, and my data is ~1m rows) which seems weird considering I can make plots using what I did before no problem. This is the primary reason I am wondering if I am understanding how to plot survival curves for my model.

Comment: Could you please add some of your code? Such as `dput(head(pharmacoSmoking, 50))`

Comment: Sorry, pharmacoSmoking is in the asaur package, not survival.  I've added that into the code above, and rechecked that the code works.  Note I'm only using the data set to illustrate my question.

Comment: if you use `type = 's'` in `plot` and `lines` you will get something closer to the ggplot